# Add additional class to breadcrumbs <div> on every page

Tags: magento-2.1, layout, html, layout-update, breadcrumbs

I am trying to add an additional class to the breadcrumbs block via a layout XML update. For example, I want the following line of code that appears below the header block by default in the blank theme:

```
<div class="breadcrumbs"></div>
```

To become as shown below on every page in the site:

```
<div class="breadcrumbs additional-class"></div>
```

So far I have added the following line of code to the app/design/frontend/[Vendor_Name]/[theme_dir]/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml file:

```
<referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs" htmlClass="breadcrumbs container-fluid" />
```

After clearing all caches the change seems to have no effect on the frontend. Has anybody had any experience trying to change the class of the breadcrumbs container div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mistaking the layout block for the markup, the markup is actually inside the template.

You need to copy this file into your theme:

```
magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/breadcrumbs.phtml
```

And add the class there:

```
<div class="breadcrumbs additional-class">
```

---

Also, I *think* `htmlClass` only works on containers and not blocks.

Comment: Thank for pointing me in the right direction Ben. My head is in my hands right now as I cant believe I didn't spot this! Lol :-)